# How to add value step by step in list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I want to add `[13178.0, 13178.0, 14130.0, 15082.0, 15082.0, 15082.0, 16034.0, 16034.0, 16986.0, 16986.0, 16986.0]` in a list, so I use

```
pred_set.append([13178.0, 13178.0, 14130.0, 15082.0, 15082.0, 15082.0, 16034.0, 16034.0, 16986.0, 16986.0, 16986.0])
```

however, the result shows they are in same row:
[image]
I want to them in different row, like the data below them, how to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `extend`:

```
l = [13005]
l.extend([13178.0, 13178.0, 14130.0, 15082.0, 15082.0, 15082.0, 16034.0, 16034.0, 16986.0, 16986.0, 16986.0])
l
```

Output:

```
[13005,
 13178.0,
 13178.0,
 14130.0,
 15082.0,
 15082.0,
 15082.0,
 16034.0,
 16034.0,
 16986.0,
 16986.0,
 16986.0]
```

Comment: This is a big duplicate, please don't answer to such, flag as duplicate to avoid spreding the answers, you can delete this post as the duplicate have been found